# Allow interactive login for group managed service account (gMSA)

Tags: managed-service-accounts

I'm trying to troubleshoot an issue with a gMSA and the error is displayed interactively. psexec is blocked by sophos, which is quite a hasle to whitelist (would be the sure way to get an interactive session).

I tried putting the gMSA in all obvious groups. Tried login via rdp, but this gives 'To sign in remotely, you need the right to......'. Tried runas. Pssession works but not interactively. start-process gives "Logon failure: the user has not been granted the requested logon type at this computer.".

Where is a gMSA blocked from logging in interactively? It's not in de deny policy, i tried adding it to interactive login policy. All to no avail. It seems it's hardcoded by Microsoft somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question : change urserAccountControl in active directory from 0x1000 (WORKSTATION_TRUST_ACCOUNT) to 0x200 (NORMAL_ACCOUNT)

Now it's basically a "normal" account. At least rdp works for me now.